# Passing data from one component to another in angular 2 (not parent to child or child to parent)?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Hello i am new in angular 2. i am stuck in the following situation. I have an ul in my homepage component. i am making a firebase api call for the job descriptions and store it to a array lets say a job array and i am showing the data in homepage like following way

```
<ul *ngFor = "let job of jobs " class="job-list" routerLink="jobdetails" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <li>{{job.nameOfThePost}}</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <li>{{job.lastDateOfApplication}}</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <li>{{job.noOfJob}}</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <li>{{job.educationalQualification}}</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
```

upon clicking on one of the li of ui i want to take user to a new component lets say jobdetails component.
Now my problem is i want to pass an array to jobdetails component. since jobdetails component isn't a child component of the homepage component how can pass data from homepage component to jobdetails component. All the help i found was on how to pass data from child to parent or parent to child. how can i do this?

Comment: shared service: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service :)

Comment: navigating with parameters: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Either Go for a Service which will Share Information from One Component to Another , its is the recommended way if it is a Small Scale application As Nesting multiple Event Emitter is not a Good way to handle data.

The other way is the Redux Approach , its is recommended for applications which are medium to Large Scale applications . In this is a concept of Store and Reducers and all the Data is Handled at a single place . This is great when you have to sync data between multiple components.

[`take a look for further info`](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you might achieve your goal.  All involve some kind of shared class.  As @AJT_82 already suggested, a shared service would be the most common way for someone new to Angular.

Another alternative would be to use NgRX and push the state information into an NgRX table that the second page could subscribe to when they get there.

You also might want to consider just passing an ID and loading the information from the database when you get to it so that the data isn't stale